# Jquery match element with matching pattern id

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an element with id `shipping_method_0_some_name_here`.

The element will always have this pattern, only the number in the middle will differantiate, and there will always be only one element like that, meaning there will never be a `shipping_method_0_some_name_here` and `shipping_method_4_some_name_here` in the same page...

So, how could I match an object with that pattern?

Something like `$('#shipping_method_{\d}_some_name_here')`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('[id^="shipping_method_"][id$="_some_name_here"]')` is the closest solution with css selectors only. you can still validate its id value with js regex

Comment: Why is the number needed in the ID if there will always be just one? Put the number in a data attribute.

Comment: I don't have control over that @Barmar. I'm just trying to catch the element to check some things on document ready...

Comment: @Sysix you should put your answer in a separate answer, as it was exactly what I needed, and I feel I should give you credit for your help!